# initState() while using TabBarView and DefaultTabController

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm loading data from firestore in the initState method. If the screen is not part of a `TabBarView()` it works as expected whereas in `TabBarView` I have to hot reload for it to loadData.

//how i created mt tabs

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true,        
      title: Text("tabs", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
      bottom: TabBar(

        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/icons/tools.png",
              height: 40,
            ),
            child: Text("tab0",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/icons/il.png",
              height: 40,
            ),
            child: Text("tab1",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            child: Text("tab2"),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            child: Text("tab3"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
      Tab0(),
      Tab2(),
      Tab2(),
     Tab3()
    ],),
  ),
);
```

Here is how I load data from cloudfirestore in Tab3:

```
getIssues() async {
  final FirebaseUser fbUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  final String user = fbUser.uid;
  return await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .document(user)
    .collection('mydata')
    .getDocuments();
}
```

My `initState`:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getIssues().then((results) {
    querySnapshot = results;
  });
}
```

Comment: Does you `TabBarView` relay on `querySnapshot ` to show information? Can you show that in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you try this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getIssues().then((results) {
    setState(() {
      querySnapshot = results;
    });
  });
}
```